# Aligning in wxpython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am trying to align checkboxes and matplotlib canvas in wx frame.

- I need those check boxes to be aligned in left side and canvas on right side
- below code not aligning them properly

can  anybody suggest changes need to be done in the code ?

- If I want to add one more canvas in the same frame how can i add it?

  ```
  import wx
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

  class canvasFrame(wx.Frame):
      def __init__(self,parent,id):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"MyCanvas",size =(1200,400))

          self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(15,5))
          self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
          self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

          b1 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Apples",(10,20),(160,-1))
          b2 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Mango",(10,40),(160,-1))

          b1sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
          b2sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
          canvSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

          b1sizer.Add(b1,0,wx.ALL,5)
          b2sizer.Add(b2,0,wx.ALL,5)
          canvSizer.Add(self.canvas,wx.TOP | wx.EXPAND,5)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = wx.App()
     frame = canvasFrame(parent=None,id = -1)
     frame.Show()
     app.MainLoop()
  ```

Comment: How about adding one canvas below the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing alot of parts of how sizers work ... I would really recommend revisiting the documentation and googling for tutorials

```
class canvasFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"MyCanvas",size =(1200,400))

        self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

        b1 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Apples",(10,20),(160,-1))
        b2 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Mango",(10,40),(160,-1))
        # first create your sizer for your checkboxes
        checkbox_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        checkbox_sizer.AddMany([b1,b2]) # add both buttons to the sizer
        #next create the main sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        #add the checkbox sizer to the main_sizer
        main_sizer.Add(checkbox_sizer)
        # add the canvas to the main sizer
        main_sizer.Add(self.canvas)
        #Set the sizer as the sizer for the frame
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        #call layout for the sizers to layout their elements
        self.Layout()
        #call fit to make the frame fit its contents
        self.Fit()
```

Comment: thank u very much Joran Beasley.Thanks for you suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You are using the sizers incorrectly, try the following:

```
import wx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class canvasFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"MyCanvas",size =(1200,400))

        self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(15,5))
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)

        b1 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Apples", size=(160,-1))
        b2 = wx.CheckBox(self,-1,"Mango", size=(160,-1))

        mainsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) # Main sizer
        cbsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # Checkbox sizer
        canvassizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # Canvas sizer

        # Add checkbox 
        cbsizer.Add(b1, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
        cbsizer.Add(b2, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)

        # Add canvas
        canvassizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 1)

        # Add "secondary" sizers to main sizer
        mainsizer.Add(cbsizer, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)
        mainsizer.Add(canvassizer, 3, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 2)

        self.SetSizer(mainsizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = wx.App()
   frame = canvasFrame(parent=None,id = -1)
   frame.Show()
   app.MainLoop()
```

Now, about the last question, i think that you would add a subplot (axes) instead other canvas, i.e.

```
self.fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(15,5))
self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.fig)
```

Comment: great answer :) you went into more details than I did ... but Im curious why you have a separate sizer for the canvas as opposed to just adding it to the mainsizer (per OP's description theres not really a need for yet another sizer.   (really to be honest I think something like a GridBagSizer would work best for OP)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I think it was for the multi canvas question (I was left with this idea xD), but of course with only one canvas the canvassizer is unnecessary. Regards.

Comment: @Jorge my second question , idea is to add one more canvas below it and a scroll bar..because when i have to plot several graphs , if i go on adding subplots , graph size will be very small rt?

Comment: @vinaykp, Oh, now I get it. Try with this example: [http://pastebin.com/eZ8qwyaX](http://pastebin.com/eZ8qwyaX). Basically the idea is to use a ScrolledPanel and add here the canvas as needed.

Comment: @Jorge exactly ..this is what i was trying to do :) thanks